# Camunda: check if message exists in the flow

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

Hei!

Is it somehow possible to check if particular message is defined (or/and handled) in the process definition? 
I have a custom endpoint which accept message and business key. I need to correlate this massage in one of the process instances, if process has number of them in different process definitions.